# Inverse in a group ring

Tags: representation-theory, group-rings

I have seen the question that is similar but I do not understand the answer whatsoever.

I have a group ring $R:=\mathbb{Q}S_3$ and want to find inverse of

$x=e+(2\,3) -(1\,3\,2)$

So is my $x^{-1}$ of the form

$e+ (a \, b)+(a\,c)+(b\,c)+(a\,b\,c)+(a\,c\,b)$

Or? And if so, how on earth do I solve using $xx^{-1}=e$?

Comment: First, your element is NOT of that form, you need a LINEAR COMBINATION of your basis elements. So write the general form of the inverse,  compute the product with $x$, and use the fact that you have a basis in order to get a linear system to solve.

Comment: by that you mean having scalars from $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Well, this is the definition of your group ring, no ?

Comment: so that would be the correct form ?